# Props are not passed with React.cloneElement in the render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have two react components, a `Layout` class and a `HomePage` class:

`HomePage` is a component which needs to have a `products` prop.

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        if (!this.props.products) {
            return (<div>Products not loaded yet</div>);
        }
        return (<div>Products loaded!</div>);
    }
}
```

`Layout` is a component that displays children coming from routes established with `react-router`.
This class is in charge to pass the `products` prop to children using `React.cloneElement`

**Layout.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';
import { Footer } from './Footer';

export class Layout extends Component {    
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          products: null,
          loading: true
      };
    }    

    // Make an api call when the component is mounted in order to pass
    // additional props to the children
    componentDidMount() {
      this.populateProductsData();
    }

    async populateProductsData() {
      const response = await fetch('api/products/all');
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ products: data, loading: false });    
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (<div>App loading</div>);
        }

        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            const props = { products: this.state.products };
            if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                return React.cloneElement(child, props);
            }
            return child;
        });

        return (
          <div>
                <NavMenu />
                {childrenWithProps}
                <Footer />
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The routing is made in an `App` component:

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Route exact path='/'
                component={HomePage}/>
        </Layout>
    );
  }
```

Hence, I am expecting to

1. Have a page with the `App loading` message while the API call hasn't been made
2. Have a page with the `Products not loaded yet` message while the prop hasn't been passed to the `Layout` children
3. Have a page with the `Products loaded!` message

However, the application is stuck at step two: the `products` prop is never received by the children components. The code compiles, there are no runtime errors, and the back-end Api is triggered and sends a valid response.

Why the `product` props will never be available in the `render()` method of the child `HomePage` component?

---

### EDIT:

Following @Nikita Chayka's answer, the props should be passed at routing:

**Layout.js**

```
export class Layout extends Component {    
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
                <NavMenu />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
          </div>
        );
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            products: null,
            loading: true
        };
    }    

    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateProductsData();
    }

    async populateProductsData() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/products/all');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ products: data, loading: false });    
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading)
            return (<div>App loading</div>);

        return (
        <Layout>
            <Route exact path='/'
                render={(props) => (<HomePage {...props} products={this.state.products}/>)}/>
        </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Layout component will pass products prop to Route component, not Home component, basically you will have

```
<Route products={} component={Home} path="/" exact/>
```

But you need to pass it down to Home, you could check for ideas here - https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-components/

EDIT

You should not provide component property to Route, only render.

Comment: You should not use component property if you use render